# UICollectionView with header pull to refresh jumps

Tags: ios, objective-c, pull-to-refresh

I'm using pull to refresh with UICollectionView that has an header(i don't know if the header is relevant) . When i'm pull to refresh right before the refresh part the collection view jumps down(not smoothly at all).

What could be the problem?

here is my code -

```
- (void)addRefresh
{
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
        [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reset) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self.refreshControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.profileCollectionView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
}
- (void)reset
{

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but not exactly the same problem with `UIRefreshControl` where the text would overlap the `UIActivityIndicator` of the `UIRefreshControl`. This would only happen the first time you would activate the `UIRefreshControl`. I'm not sure if this fix will help you but you can give it a try:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //Fix for bug where spinner would overlap the text
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_refreshControl beginRefreshing];
        [_refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });
}
```